# How to draw grouped bar chart in Android with different number of columns in each group?

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, mpandroidchart

This is the chart that I want to create (click on the link to view image):
[Desired chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alCsw.png)

I have researched a lot about Grouped Bar Chart in MPAndroidChart but that library seems to restrict. Each group must have the same number of columns and the column order must be consistent. Does anyone know how to create a grouped bar chart like in my image using MPAndroidChart (or any other libraries)?
Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code?

```
List<String> xValues = ...; // "Shop1", "Shop2", "Shop3"

XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyValueFormatter(xValues));

// create 2 datasets 
BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(valuesProduct1, "Product1"); //valuesProduct1 are the values corresponding to the shops, 
set1.setColor(Color.BLUE);

BarDataSet set2 = new BarDataSet(valuesProduct2, "Product2");
set2.setColor(Color.RED);

BarData data = new BarData(set1, set2);
chart.setData(data);
chart.groupBars(...); // available since release v3.0.0
chart.invalidate(); // refresh
```

If you have some troubles where the shop has no products, just put zero on the concrete position

Comment: Thanks kboskin for your answer, but unfortunately your solution doesn't work because my code is currently similar to yours and I still can't create grouped bar chart like my image.